# Find joint distribution of distance to origin from points chosen uniformly inside spheres

Tags: probability

I have the following problem.

A point $P $ is chosen uniformly from the unit sphere $|X |\le1$, where $X \in R^3 $. Then an other point $P' $ is chosen uniformly from the sphere centered at the origin with radius equal to $ |P |$.

Let $U= |P | $ and $V =|P' | $, that is the distances to the origin , what is the joint distribution of $U $ and $V $?

I think I'm supposed to use the change of variable formula defined as in 7. [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Transformations.html), but other than that I don't know how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second paragraph implies that $|P|=1$

Comment: I assume you mean to say that $P$ is chosen uniformly from the unit ball, i.e., the points $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\left|x\right|\le 1$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the CDF of the norm of a point $Z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that is uniformly distributed within the closed ball of radius $r_0 > 0$ equals $F_{|Z|}(r) \triangleq \mathbb{P}(|Z| \leq r) = (r/r_0)^3$, $0 \leq r \leq r_0$, with corresponding PDF $f_{|Z|}(r) = \frac{d}{dr}F_{|Z|}(r)= 3r^2/r_0^3$, $0\leq r\leq r_0$.

It then follows that $f_U(u)=3u^2$, $0\leq u\leq1$ and $f_{V|U}(v|u)=3v^2/u^3$, $0 \leq v\leq u$.

Application of the chain rule gives
\begin{align}
f_{U,V}(u,v) &= f_{U}(u) f_{V|U}(v|u) \\
&= 9v^2/u,\; 0\leq v\leq u \leq 1
\end{align}